# If the Fourier coefficient $\hat{f}(k)$ of $f\in C^1(\mathbb T)$ is zero for all $|k|<N$, then $\|f’\|_{L^\infty}\geq4N \|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Tags: fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb T)=C^1(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ be a function such that
> $$\hat f(k):=\int_{\mathbb T}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}\,dx=0,\qquad \forall k\in\{-N+1,\cdots,-1,0,1,\cdots, N-1\}.$$
> Show that $\|f'\|_{L^\infty}\geq 4N\|f\|_{L^\infty}$.

Here is my attempt. Since for $f\in C(\mathbb T)$, the Cesàro mean
$$\sigma_n f(x):=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}S_j f(x):=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\sum_{k=-j}^j\hat f(k)e^{2\pi ikx}$$
converges to $f$ in $L^\infty$, it suffices to estimate on $\|\sigma_n f\|_{L^\infty}$ and then pass the limit. Integration by parts gives $\widehat{f'}(k)=2\pi ik\hat f(k)$, and so for any $n\geq N$ we have
$$\sigma_nf(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}S_j f(x)=\frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=N}^{n}\left(\sum_{k=-j}^{-N}+\sum_{k=N}^j\right)\frac{\widehat{f'}(k)}{2\pi ik}e^{2\pi ikx}.$$ Now I don’t know how to continue.

Any hints are welcome!

Comment: Not sure for this inequality. Compare it with so called Bernstein inequality relating norm of derivative of polynomial degree $m$ as $max|p^{'}(e^{2{\pi}t})| <= m*max|p(e^{2{\pi}*t}|$. If you use it with a polynomial of degree $2n$ and add to it your inequality you would get that $2>4$.

Comment: the result holds with $\pi$ instead of $4$ by some standard manipulations

Comment: note that Bernstein theorem applied to a trigonometric polynomial of degree $M \ge N$ gives the reverse inequality with $2\pi M$ in that particular case, as we can see in the case of the monomial $e^{2\pi iN}$ for $M=N$, so there is no contradiction with the statement above and the inequality may very well hold with $4N$ but standard arguments prove it only with $\pi N$

Comment: @Conrad Are you sure the result holds for $\pi$? I want to know what is the ‘usual manipulations’. Can you share here? This is a homework problem in my harmonic analysis course. In the next lecture I will ask my professor for a hint.

Comment: actually, I was wrong and the constant is indeed $4$ - solution below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We prove that if $f$ periodic and differentiable on $[0,1]$ with $f'$ bounded (eg $f'$ continuous) and $f(x)=\sum_{|k| \ge N}a_ke^{2\pi ikx}$ is the Fourier series of $f$ where $N \ge 1$ is a fixed integer, then $||f'||_{\infty} \ge 4N||f||_{\infty}$.

Let $\widehat{f'}(k)=b_k=2\pi ika_k$ so $a_k=\frac{b_k}{2\pi i k}, |k| \ge N$

We use the well known Fourier series for $\psi(x)=x-1/2, x \in [0,1]$ and a result of Vaaler regarding its $L^1$ approximation by trigonometric polynomials of degree at most $N-1$

It is well known and not hard to prove that $\psi(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{\sin 2\pi kx}{k}, 0<x<1$ (with bounded convergence). But since $\sin 2\pi kx=\frac{1}{2i}e^{2\pi ikx}-\frac{1}{2i}e^{-2\pi ikx}$ so $\psi(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\sum_{|k|\ne 0}\frac{e^{2\pi ikx}}{k}, 0<x<1$, one has that the Fourier coefficients of $\psi*f'$ are precisely $-\frac{b_k}{2\pi ik}, |k| \ge N$ hence $\psi*f'=-f$ ae by general theory (integrable functions with same Fourier coefficient are equal ae)

But now if we perturb $\psi$ by any trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $N-1$ and we get an $\eta=\psi-P_{N-1}$ we still have $\eta*f'=-f$ hence $||f||_{\infty}=||\eta*f'||_{\infty} \le ||\eta||_1||f'||_{\infty}$ and in particular if we find $||\eta||_1 \le \frac{1}{4N}$ we are done

But now [Vaaler theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-12/issue-2/Some-extremal-functions-in-Fourier-analysis/bams/1183552525.full) (Theorem 17, p 208, paper "Some extremal functions in Fourier analysis" linked here) gives precisely this result by exhibiting a trigonometric polynomial $\psi*i_{N-1}$ of degree $N-1$ st $\eta_{N-1}=\psi-\psi*i_{N-1}$ satisfies $||\eta_{N-1}||_1 = \frac{1}{4N}$ (and moreover showing that this the best we can do so for any other trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $N-1$ the integral above is at least $\frac{1}{4N}$ with equality only for $\psi*i_{N-1}$), so the problem is solved!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My professor just gave me a hint which is on the same track as yours. About the final part, I'm a little missing. The professor lets me to prove the existence of $g\in\text{span}_{\mathbb R}\{\sin(2\pi jt): j\in\mathbb Z\cap (0,N)\}$ such that $g(\frac{j}{2N})=\frac{N-j}{2N}$ for all $j\in\mathbb Z\cap(0,2N)$ and then show $\int_0^1|g(t)+t-1/2|\,dt=\frac1{4N}$. I can show the existence and uniqueness of $g$ but fail to show the integral equality. Can you help me? Is the function $g$ the same as your $\psi*i_{N-1}$?

Comment: show that $g(t)-\psi(t)$ has the same sign as $\sin 2\pi Nt$ and let $h_N(t)$ the signum function of  $\sin 2\pi Nt$ which has a well known Fourier series $h(t)=\frac{2}{\pi i}\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i (2k+1)2Nt}}{2k+1}$ so it is orthogonal on $g$; this means that $\int_0^1|g(t)-\psi(t)|dt=\int_0^1(g(t)-\psi(t))h(t)dt=-\int_0^1\psi(t)h(t)dt$ and the latter is easily computed to be $1/4N$ using the Fourier series above and the fact that $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}=\pi^2/4$

Comment: Understand now！Thank you！