# If the Fourier coefficient $\hat{f}(k)$ of $f\in C^1(\mathbb T)$ is zero for all $|k|<N$, then $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq \frac CN \|f'\|_{L^\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof, harmonic-analysis

> Let $f\in C^1(\mathbb T)=C^1(\mathbb R/\mathbb Z)$ be a function such that
> $$\hat f(k):=\int_{\mathbb T}f(x)e^{-2\pi ikx}\,dx=0,\qquad \forall k\in\{-N+1,\cdots,-1,0,1,\cdots, N-1\}.$$
> Show that $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq \frac CN \|f'\|_{L^\infty}$ for some $C>0$ indpendent of $f$ and $N$.

The best constant $C$ is $\frac14$, as shown by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4395619/624428), in which the proof uses a very "hard" theorem due to [Vaaler](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-12/issue-2/Some-extremal-functions-in-Fourier-analysis/bams/1183552525.full).

I'm trying to prove the decay rate $N^{-1}$ and I don't care about the best constant $C$. I'm looking for an easier proof.

**First Try.** By Cauchy inequality and the Plancherel identity,
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_{L^\infty}&\leq\sum_{|k|\geq N}|\hat f(k)|=\sum_{|k|\geq N}\frac{\left|\widehat{f'}(k)\right|}{2\pi |k|}\\
&\leq \frac1{2\pi}\left(\sum_{|k|\geq N}\left|\widehat{f'}(k)\right|^2\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{|k|\geq N}\frac1{|k|^2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq \frac1{2\pi}\left\|f'\right\|_{L^2}\left(\frac2N\right)^{1/2}=\frac C{\sqrt N}\left\|f'\right\|_{L^2}\\
&\leq \frac C{\sqrt N}\left\|f'\right\|_{L^\infty}\ \ .
\end{align*}

The deacy rate on $N$ is not good enough to get the desired result.

**Second Try.** (Also failed.) As Sarvesh Ravichandran Iyer suggested in the comments, using some ideas in the proof that I quoted above, I've made some progress. In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4395619/624428), let $\psi(x)=x-1/2, x \in [0,1]$, then $$\psi(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k \ge 1}\frac{\sin 2\pi kx}{k}, 0<x<1$$
and $\psi*f'=-f$. If we perturb $\psi$ by any trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $N-1$ and we get an $\eta=\psi-P_{N-1}$ we still have $\eta*f'=-f$ hence $||f||_{\infty}=||\eta*f'||_{\infty} \le ||\eta||_1||f'||_{\infty}$ and in particular if we find $||\eta||_1 \le \frac{C}{N}$ then we are done. A natural candidate is
$$\eta(x)=\psi(x)+\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{1\leq k\leq N-1}\frac{\sin 2\pi kx}{k}=-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k \ge N}\frac{\sin 2\pi kx}{k}.$$
Now, the problem reduces to show that $||\eta||_1 \le \frac{C}{N}$ for this special function $\eta$, where $C>0$ is independent of $N$. To explore the oscillation in this summation, we can use the partial sum method. Let $S_M(x)=\sum_{k=N}^M \sin(2\pi kx)$, then
$$S_M(x)=-\frac{\cos((2M+1)\pi x)-\cos((2N-1)\pi x)}{2\sin \pi x}=\frac{\sin((M+N)\pi x)\sin((M-N+1)\pi x)}{\sin\pi x}.$$
The partial sum method applied on $\eta$ gives that
$$\eta(x)=-\frac1\pi\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac1{k(k+1)}S_k(x).$$
Note that near $x=0$, the denominator is small, hence, naturally we split the integral into two parts: $\int_0^{1/2}|\eta|=\int_0^\delta+\int_\delta^{1/2}$. By Plancherel we have
$$\int_0^\delta |\eta(x)|\,dx\leq \delta^{1/2}\left(\int_0^\delta|\eta(x)|^2\,dx\right)^{1/2}\leq C\delta^{1/2}\left(\sum_{k=N}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\right)^{1/2}\leq C\sqrt{\frac\delta N}.$$
To get the correct decay rate $N^{-1}$, it seems that $\delta=1/N$ is a good choice. It remains to estimate $\int_\delta^{1/2}|\eta|$, we have
$$\int_\delta^{1/2}|\eta(x)|\,dx\leq C\sum_{k=N}^\infty \frac1{k(k+1)} \int_\delta^{1/2}\frac1{|\sin(\pi x)|}\,dx\leq C\frac {|\log \delta|}{N}=C\frac{\log N}N.$$
Therefore, $\|\eta\|_1\le C\frac{\log N}N$. This implies that $\|f\|_{L^\infty}\leq C\frac{\log N}N \|f'\|_{L^\infty}$, which is better than my first try, but not satisfactory either.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Going back to the post attached by you, it is proved that $\psi * f' = -f$ a.e. where $\psi$ is an explicit function. It is then proved that $\eta = \psi - P_{N-1}$ can be used to replace $\psi$ where $P_{N-1}$ is any trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $N-1$. The bound then used results in $\|f'\|_{\infty} \leq \|\eta\|_1 \|f'\|_{\infty}$. All you are left to argue, instead of using Vaaler's result, is that there exists an $\eta$ such that $\|\eta\|_{1} \leq \frac{C}{N}$ for some constant $C>0$ independent of $N$. This amounts to the existence of good enough $P_{N-1}$.

Comment: There is an obvious candidate for $P_{N-1}$, namely the bunch of degree at most $N-1$ terms of the function $\psi$ itself. Try removing those and seeing if the rest has $L^1$ norm at most $\frac{C}{N}$? A look at Vaaler's paper may help.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks for your comments! You idea  sounds natural! I've made a second try following your hints, see my edits above. However, I still cannot get the desired inequality. I've also had a read on Vaaler's paper, and I cannot find useful information. Could you please hint a little more? Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried smoothing out $\psi$  and $\eta$ via convolution with an approximate identity  $\phi_{\delta}$ to eliminate the discontinuity in $\eta$?  This would improve the decay rate of  its Fourier coefficients.  And the smoothed versions of $\psi$ should  be good approximations to $\psi$ that can be estimated directly. Also $\hat (\eta *\phi)(k)= \hat \eta(k) \hat \phi(k)$.

Comment: @Feng I will take a second look when I can, thanks

Comment: there is a direct though still nontrivial proof in Katznelson's classic book (Introduction to Harmonic Analysis) page $49$ with constant $12$ which again reduces to finding a clever  function and uses some subtle properties of trigonometric series with positive convex coefficients that go to zero (such are actually Fourier series of non negative functions)

Comment: @Conrad Thanks for your comment! The book sounds interesting to me! I'll have a look at it, maybe read some chapters of it if I have spare time. Now, it seems that "easy proofs" for the inequality I expect don't exist at all, which probably means that this inequality is very strong! It surprised me! Since this inequality looks so correct... Any way, thank you for your sharing!

Comment: @MathWonk I haven't think about that. Maybe the choice of the function $\phi$ in the approximation identity is imporant, too. Conrad has shared a reference which contains a direct proof, which also uses the "smoothing out" ideas. It is interesting that, if we replace $C^1$ by $C^2$, we can get $N^{-2}$ deacy without using the convolution procedure! Thanks again for your advice!

Comment: Note that for even order eg $C^2$ the proof with now ($n^{-2}$) is easier by symmetry since for negative indices, even powers of them are same as for the positive indices so it's easier to construct an accessory function say and the proof is simpler for all evens than for the odd cases like $1$ here